# AWS CloudWatch ECS CPU utilization per instance dashboard graphs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch, dashboard

In AWS CloudWatch, is there a to create a graph on a dashboard that provides an overlay of line graphs, one for each of my ECS target instances, showing the CPU utilization?

I have an ECS Fargate cluster with a scaling policy that adds and removes instances based on some criteria. At any time there may be one or many hosts (let's say up to 10 as an arbitrary maximum number) active in the cluster. There is no way to know ahead of time which hosts are active or what there IDs will be.

I would like to have a graph on a dashboard showing me a line graph of the CPU utilization for each active host, all overlaid on the same graph. (Note that I'm not taking a survey of how many people think this would be useful or how many people would find it easy to read. I'm asking how to do it.)

I of course am aware of the ECS `CPUUtilization` metric, which is useful, but it seems to provide some sort of aggregate value across the entire cluster, no? I want a separate graph line for each active instance. Is that possible?

Comment: That metric is an average CPU utilization for all tasks in the service. CloudWatch does not natively support per-task metrics for ECS Fargate services, only per-service metrics.

Comment: You have to enable Container Insights on the ECS cluster to get the per-instance/service/task/container metrics https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/ContainerInsights.html Enabling that incurs an additional cost